# How do I insert things that automatically include text collected from throughout the document?

Tags: microsoft-word

At a previous job, I worked with Word documents that had 'things' that contained text that was collected from throughout the document.

One would mark text as - for example - a "To Do" item, or as an "Incomplete" item, and at the end of the document were placed these 'things', one showing all of the "To Do" items in the document, and another showing all "Incomplete" items in the document.

These 'things' were not created by hand.  They would automatically collect appropriate text from throughout the document.  The functionality was in Word itself and was not provided by an add-on.

The text to include in the 'things' may have been marked as such using custom styles for - for example - "To Do" and "Incomplete".

But I don't remember how to create those 'things' (some kind of table?) that would show all of the "To Do" and "Incomplete" items - nor what that feature was called.

How do I accomplish this?  I'm using Word 2010.  (At the previous job we used Word 2003, so this is not a new feature.)

Comment: have a look here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-index-and-update-an-index-cc502c71-a605-41fd-9a02-cda9d14bf073

Comment: While that may work, I found what I was looking for.  It's an easier solution.  Tables of contents show text from elsewhere in the document.  By default, text styled as H1, H2, and H3.  But they can be configured to show arbitrary styles.  And you can have multiple TOCs - for example, one for "To Do" items and one for "Incomplete" items.  This shows how it's done: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-a-custom-style-to-annotate-a-word-table-of-contents/

Comment: great you've solved it! Please write it as an answer for you own question to help others with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tables of contents show text from elsewhere in the document.  By default, text styled as H1, H2, and H3.  But they can be configured to show arbitrary styles.  And you can have multiple TOCs - for example, one for "To Do" items and one for "Incomplete" items.

This shows how it's done: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-a-custom-style-to-annotate-a-word-table-of-contents/